# How to make an API call(Mashape) with the below parameters using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire, mashape

Im building a small app in Swift 3 for iOS and the api I'm consuming for getting the data for the app has a cURL request. 
The cURL request of the API is as follows:

```
    //        curl -X POST --include 'https://myApi.mashape.com/' \
    //        -H 'X-Mashape-Key:APIKEY' \
    //        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    //        -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    //        --data-binary '{"parameter1":"value","parameter2":"value"}'
```

Using Swift and Alamofire, this is the api call Im making to fetch the data using POST method.

```
    func networkFunction(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {


    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "X-Mashape-Key":"APIKEY",
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "parameter1" : "value",
        "parameter2" : "value"
    ]
    Alamofire.request("https://myApi.mashape.com",method: .post,parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON
        { response in

            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")

            let result = response.result
            print(response.description)

            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> {
                if let parameter1 = dict["parameter1"] as? String {
                    self._parameter1= parameter1

                }
                if letparameter2 = dict["parameter2"] as? String {
                    self._parameter2 = parameter2
                    print(parameter2)
                }
            }
        completed()
        }

    }
```

When I do the above I get an error in the console as a bad request. 
I have tried changing the function call but the result is the same. What is going wrong in the API call above?

Edit: I have added the solution in the answer below.

Comment: It seems you are not using the end path, just the absolute url. Check if you are using the correct url with endpoint, like `https://myApi.mashape.com/someEndpoint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error stemmed from the fact that :

1. The ordering of the parameters wasn't right
2. I had omitted adding the JSON Encoding parameter.

The final call with the changes looks like this :

```
Alamofire.request("https://myAPI.mashape.com/beta",method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON
        { response in
          ...
          ...
          ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace that line in your code..

```
Alamofire.request(URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://myApi.mashape.com")!),method: .post,parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON
```